# How to import non-comma/tab separated ASCII numerical data and render into vector (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, import, ascii, matlab-figure

I want to import 100,000 digits of pi into matlab and manipulate it as a vector.  I've copied and pasted these digits from [here](http://www.angio.net/pi/digits/100000.txt) and saved them in a text file.  I'm now having a lot of trouble importing these digits and rendering them as a vector.

I've found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19265-calculate-pi-decimals) function which calculates the digits within matlab.  However, even with this I'm having trouble turning the output into a vector which I could then, for example, plot.  (Plus it's rather slow for 100,000 digits, at least on my computer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textscan` for that:

```
fid = fopen('100000.txt','r');
PiT = textscan(fid,'%c',Inf);
fclose(fid);
```

`PiT` is a cell array, so convert it to a vector of chars:

```
PiT = cell2mat(PiT(1));
```

Now, you want a vector of int, but you have to discard the decimal period to use the standard function:

```
Pi = cell2mat(textscan(PiT([1,3:end]),'%1d', Inf));
```

Note: if you delete (manually) the period, you can do that all in once:

```
fid = fopen('100000.txt','r');
Pi = cell2mat(textscan(fid,'%1d',Inf));
fclose(fid);
```

**EDIT**

Here is another solution, using `fscanf`, as `textscan` may not return a cell-type result.

Read the file with `fscanf`:

```
fid = fopen('100000.txt','r');
Pi = fscanf(fid,'%c');
fclose(fid);
```

Then take only the digits and convert the string as digits:

```
Pi = int32(Pi((Pi>='0')&(Pi<='9')))-int32('0');
```

Function `int32` may be replaced by other conversion functions (e.g. `double`).

Comment: On my coputer MATLAB crashes at the line Pi = cell2mat(textscan(fid,'%1d',Inf)); or PiT = textscan(fid,'%c',Inf);

Comment: Using fscanf(fid,'%c') without specifying "Inf" works without crashing, but then cell2mat gives me an error message "Cell contents reference from a non cell array object".  So I am left with the cell format which I cannot convert to a vector of floating point numbers.

Comment: @ben I'm working with Matlab R2013b... and it works properly with your file. But what is the type of the variable returned by `fscanf`? I edit my answer to put a note with `fscanf`

Comment: I'm using R2010a.  Type of variable is "char" according to class(PiT)

Comment: @ben Ok, I post a solution working with `fscanf`. I'm quite sure that this function has not changed recently. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one line.

When you modify your text file to just include the post-comma digits **14...** you can use `fscanf` to get the vector you want.

```
pi = fscanf( fopen('pi.txt'), '%1d' );  fclose all
```

or without modifying the file:

```
pi = str2double( regexp( fscanf( fopen('pi.txt') ,'%1c'), '[0-9]', 'match'));
```