# How to turn a string of numbers into a vector of floating point numbers in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, vector

In matlab, how can I turn a string or cell of digits into a vector of numbers, where each digit in the string is an element in the vector.

That is, for eg., how to turn this:

```
A=3141592;
```

(where class(A)=char)

into this:

```
A=[3 1 4 1 5 9 2];
```

(where class(A)=double)

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213914/how-to-import-non-comma-tab-separated-ascii-numerical-data-and-render-into-vecto/23214964?noredirect=1#comment35527913_23214964)

Answer (score 3):

Subtract ascii value of `'0'` from each of the ascii characters that constitute the string in `A` to get the double array -

```
A-'0'
```

Straight away plugging in the ascii value would work too -

```
A-48
```

Output -

```
ans =

     3     1     4     1     5     9     2
```